# Break apart makes intersecting nodes not so smooth and creates an additional stroke

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

I want to break apart my latter , which has no fill , but just a stroke. So basically i just have the below letter with a stroke:

[image]

So basically what i did to get to here is , i typed the letter, then i added a stroke of `5px` . I removed the fill , Now i take the node tool and drag it over the letter , then, `path->storke to path`, Now i have this letter with all these nodes and i want each of these nodes to `break apart`. But from here on, i get everything wrong and unable to correctly break apart the borders into indivisual components.

Heres what i tried , since i have all these nodes , i drag over the letter again the nodes tool to select the nodes , then i click on `break path at selected nodes` , now i go to `path->break apart` , I get the following:

[image]

So you can see there are two problems with this , i get an additional pair of stroke and secondly , the place where the nodes intersect initially seem to be a bit broken , i mean not so smooth. How do i solve these 2 issues ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're converting the stroke to a path. You don't need to do that. That creates a filled object like a rectangle. You want a line. Try it without converting stroke to path. Just highlight the nodes and break apart and it should work.

EDIT Here's a pic that shows the difference.

[image: Difference between stroke & filled object]